# Compiler calls to no-arg super() in argumented constructors of child classes in java

Tags: java, constructor

Here we goes:

```
public class Parent {

    public Parent(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String name = null;

}

public class Child extends Parent {

    public Child(String name) {
        super(name); // If I comment this : Implicit super constructor Parent() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor
    }

}
```

It is said that *"if you don't invoke the super constructor by your self, the compiler will insert a no-arg call to super() for you, as the very first statement in the constructor."*

- Is this true for the argument-ed constructors as well?
- Mustn't the compiler call the argument-ed super constructor with the same signature of the child constructor?
- Why it has been designed like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this true for the argument-ed constructors as well?

Yes.

> Mustn't the compiler call the argument-ed super constructor with the same signature of the child constructor?

No.  If you want a different base-class constructor to be invoked, you must call it yourself, passing arguments as necessary.

> Why it has been designed like this?

Because the alternative you're proposing (automatically forwarding all arguments) wouldn't be very useful in general.

Comment: @ Oli : Thank you for the answer. "Wouldn't be very useful in general" means it is not wrong but not useful. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @NamalFernando: Define "wrong" ;)  All I mean is that there would be few situations where argument forwarding would be what the developer required.

Answer (score 0):

The *it is said* statement is inaccurate.  A constructor of a child class that does not begin with an invocation of one of the constructors of its superclass, or with a chained invocation of another constructor of the class itself implicitly has the no-argument constructor of the superclass inserted.

It is quite possible and often quite usable to invoke a superclass constructor with a different signature.  Consider this hypothetical one:

```
public class SquareRootException extends IllegalArgumentException {
    public SquareRootException(double negativeValue) {
        super(String.format("Attempt to take the square root of the negative number %f",
              negativeValue);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Why should the programmer write unnecessary code?